# PHP gettext doesn't works

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

Apache 2.4 + PHP 5.5

```
putenv('LC_ALL=ru_RU');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');
bindtextdomain('mydomain', '/absolute/path/to/messages');
textdomain('mydomain');
```

I'm absolutely sure, than I've `mydomain.po` and `mydomain.mo` files in `/absolute/path/to/messages/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/`.
Also I gave these files to my colleague on OS X Maverics - worked fine.
I can't make php gettext working.

**I've googled/stackoverflowed for about couple of hours, tried various solutions - still not working. What I do wrong?**

I restart apache every time I change something to ensure gettext files is being reloaded.

Here is my `locale -a` output:

```
miraage@ubuntu:~$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
....
en_GB.utf8
....
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
ru_UA.utf8
```

One more cmd output:

```
miraage@ubuntu:~$ sudo locale-gen ru
Generating locales...
  ru_RU.UTF-8... up-to-date
  ru_UA.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Okay, I've figured out:

`sudo locale-gen ru_RU` (added new locale, but different charset)
and
then `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');` did all work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? You always get the same catalogue? You get not catalogue at all? And error message? What do `setlocale()` and `textdomain()` return?

Comment: `setlocale()` returned `false`, `textdomain()` returned **mydomain**.
Thanks for comment. Will try to figure out locale.

Comment: I used `putenv('LANG=ru_RU');` - did not know that you set `LC_ALL` there?

Comment: You possibly need `setlocale(..., 'ru_RU.utf8')`. `ru_RU` is not in `locale -a`'s output.

Comment: Tried `ru`, `ru_RU`, `ru_RU.utf8`. Still no result.

Comment: Did you set your codeset too? `bind_textdomain_codeset(<domain>, 'utf-8');` Well - this won't help you too thought, because your error is in setlocale. Did you try this `putenv` which I posted?

Comment: @Jurik yes, tried both `utf8` and `UTF-8`. Maybe problem not in PHP?

Comment: @Miraage since `setlocal` does not work, I thought the error must be before this and I did not know that you set `LC_ALL` at this place. So did you try `putenv('LANG=ru_RU');`?

Comment: `putenv('LANG=ru');`
`putenv('LANG=ru_RU');`
`putenv('LANG=ru_RU.utf8');`
`putenv('LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8');`
nothing helped.

Comment: Until `setlocale()` finally returns `true` there's nothing that locale based functions can do. Using `putenv()` simply skips error checking.

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time asked question, but maybe one more check will help someone who will try everything "just by instruction" and still doesn't work.

That is collision with `LANGUAGE` environment variable.

In my case a while ago after a long fight, I figured out that it was causing the issue. Removing that environment variable `export LANGUAGE=` (empty, after `=`) resolved normal `setLocale` behavior.